Getting Domain range Error using mapview function. Screenshot attached

Getting:

Error in leaflet::colorNumeric(palette = palette, domain = domain,
na.color = na.color) :     Wasn't able to determine range of domain

Trying to attribute certain areas of map with a color

It's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please do not post code or data in images
